# SP 2010 Log Shipping Configuration

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, log-shipping

I have searched the web and found little to no answers for this kind of question...

I am setting up our new Disaster Recovery server and have the server all ready to go.  I discovered that our temporary DBA had set up log shipping to the SQL DR server with the No Recovery choice instead of Stand By / Read only.

I want to be able to attach to the Content Databases while they are in a read only state.  To do this I'll need to change the setting from No Recovery to Stand By. Is there a special process to make this change, or is it as easy and changing the setting and it's all done?

We are on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Matt Engel
SharePoint Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the DR server databases in Standby AND Read-only is NORMAL.  The log shipping restoration process of restoring data from the .trn worked just fine while keeping the database in the Standby/Read-Only state.  You don't have to change this at all.

Standard protocol is to restore logs shipped with a job running every 15 minutes.  Primary does full backups daily and copies logs every 15 minutes and then DR restores every 15 minutes.  Sometimes a Database will get put in a "Restoring" state if there are are lot of records in the .trn files to pump into the tables into a given database ( you will see a green arrow pointing north (up)  )